# Trying to understand this simple python code

Tags: python-3.x

I was reading Jeff Knupp's blog and I came across this easy little script:

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
    if n > 1:
        if n == 2:
            return True
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return False
        for current in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n) + 1), 2):
            if n % current == 0:
                return False
        return True
    return False

print(is_prime(17))
```

(note: I added the import math at the beginning.  You can see the original here:
http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/)

This is all pretty straightforward and I get the majority of it, but I'm not sure what's going on with his use of the range function.  I haven't ever used it this way or seen anyone else use it this way, but then I'm a beginner.  What does it mean for the range function to have three parameters, and how does this accomplish testing for primeness?

Also (and apologies if this is a stupid question), but the very last 'return False' statement.  That is there so that if a number is passed to the function that is less than one (and thus not able to be prime), the function won't even waste its time evaluating that number, right?

Answer (score 1):

[The third is the step.](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) It iterates through every odd number less than or equal to the square root of the input (3, 5, 7, etc.).

Comment: Okay, thanks for clearing that up for me.  What's the rationale for using the square root of the input?  Couldn't a prime number have potential factors which exceed its square root?

Comment: Yes. Exactly one. Itself.

Comment: Of course.  My question is: why is it acceptable to use  sqrt + 1 of the number as the upper bound of the range function?  I tried working a few examples by hand to get a feel for what was going on, by looxing at 459 (17 X 27), for example. I found that sqrt + 1 was always a bit bigger than the smaller number I used.  But if I use 7919 (which is prime, but let's assume I don't know that yet), what property of prime numbers let's me stop looking for factors after sqrt + 1?

Comment: Stopping after sqrt(n) + 1 isn't for prime numbers, it's for *composite* numbers. Prime numbers will *only ever* have two factors.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math #import math module

def is_prime(n): #define is_prime function  and assign variable n to its argument (n = 17 in this example).
    if n > 1: #check if n (its argument) is greater than one, if so, continue; else return False (this is the last return in the function).
        if n == 2: #check if n equals 2, it so return True and exit.
            return True
        if n % 2 == 0: #check if the remainder of n divided by two equas 0, if so, return False (is not prime) and exit. 
            return False
        for current in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n) + 1), 2): #use range function to generate a sequence starting with value 3 up to, but not including, the truncated value of the square root of n, plus 1. Once you have this secuence give me every other number ( 3, 5, 7, etc)     
            if n % current == 0: #Check every value from the above secuence and if the remainder of n divided by that value is 0, return False (it's not prime)
                return False
        return True #if not number in the secuence divided n with a zero remainder then n is prime, return True and exit.  
    return False

print(is_prime(17))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, the commented code was quite helpful.  You said the range function would start with value one, but don't the parameters specify that it would start with 3?